# Facing problem to cover test class 75% coverage

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-communities

This is my batch class. I am facing a problem in the test class.
So please give me some solution on it. How to write this condition into class or how to write a test class for this.

I have this batch class created:

```
public class processBatch implements database.Batchable<object>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Scheduable{
public string AccountURL;
public String ProcessURL;
Public String Key;

   private class JsonUpsertResult
{
   List<Database.Error> Error {get;set;}
   string SFDCId{get;set;}
   String visibleID{get;set;}
   Boolean is Created {get;set;}

   Boolean isSuccess {get;set;}
}

public ProcessBatch(){

   SAP_Details__c SAP = SAP_Details__c. getOrgDefaults();
   AccountURL =SAP.Account_API_URL__c;
   ProcessURL =SAP.process_API_URL__c;
   Key =SAP.API_Key__c;
   system.debug('API:' + ProcessURL + '-' + Key);
   }

public Iterable<Object> start (Database.BatchableContext BC) {

   List<Object> results =new List <Object>();
   
   http http = new http();
   httpRequest request =new HttpRequest();
   system.debug('API:' '+ ProcessURL+' -' + Key);
   request.setEndpoint(ProcessURL);
   request.setMethod('POST');
   request.setHeader('Authorization', Key);
   request.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
   request.setHeader ('content-type', 'application/json');
   }';

   request.setBody(filters);
   HttpResponse response =http.send(request);
   
if(responce.getStatusCode() == 200){
   SAPProcessJsonApex2 gt = {SAPProcessJSON2Apex2) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), SAPProcessJSON2Apex.class);
   List<SAPProcessJson2Apex.Result> res =gt.result;
   system.debug('Size of Result: ' + res.size());

   results = res;
}
   return results;
}

public void execute (Database. BatchableContext BC, List<object> scope){

List<JSON2Apex.Results) accountResults = new List<JSON2Apex.Results>;
List<Process__c> ProcessToUpsert = new List<Process__c> ();
List<Process_Agent__c> CollectivesToupsert = new List<Process_Agent__c> ();
List<Department__c> departmentToupdate = new List<Department__c> ();
List<JSON2Apex.Results) revisedAccRes = new List JSON2Apex.Results> ();
List<SAPprocessJSON2Apex2.Results res = (List<SAPprocessJSO2Apex2.Results>) scope();

List<SAPprocessJSON2Apex2.Results revisedRes = nen List<SAPprocessJSONApex2.Results> ();

for (SAPprocessJSON2Apex2.Results r: res) {

   SAPprocessJSON2Apex2.Document doc = r. document: List<SAPprocessJSON2 Apex2. Companies) comp = doc.companies;

List<SAPprocessJSON2Apex2.Companies> comp = doc.companies;
List<String> processTypes = doc.processTypes;
Lisk<String> categories = doc.categories;


Process__c pr = new Process__c ();
pr.Visibleprocess_No__c = doc.processId;
pr.Visible_method__c = 'SAP';
pr.process_Description__c = doc.description;

pr.Amount__c = doc.Amount; 
pr.Construction_Type__c = doc.constructionType;

if(doc.phase == 'First planning'){
   pr.Division=='First planning!';
} else if(doc.phase == 'Quotation'){
   pr.Division == 'Main Step Quotation; 
} else if(doc.phase = 'Contract Get') {
   pr. Division== ' Main Step Agricultural';
}

pr.process_Full Name = doc.title; 
pr.Name = doc.title.left (80);

if (categories.size() > 0){
if(categories [0] == 'Factory' || categories [0] = 'Storage' ){
pr.Sector__c = 'Industrial';
}else if(categories [0] == 'Packaging/Storage') {
pr. Type_of_Sector_c = 'Warehouse'; 
}else if(categories[0] == 'Shops and Retail' || categories [0]=='Any Showrooms') {
pr.Sector__c = 'Commercial'; 
}

if(pr.Sector__c != null && doc.Amount >= 50000){
ProcessToUpsert.ada (p); 
revisedRes.ada (r);
} } }

public void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}

public void execute (SchedulableContext sc) {
database.executeBatch (new ProcessBatch (), 30);
}
}
```

`&& d.Amount__c>= 50000` Whenever I write this condition in my class then my test class covers only 35%, and when I remove this condition it covers 80%. This condition is correct according to the requirement.

**Test Class**

```
@isIest (SeeAllData = true) 
public class ProcessBatchTest {
@isTest public static void processBatchTest () {
Test.setMock (HttpCalloutMock.class, new HttpMock()); 
ProcessBatch pb = new ProcessBatch(); 
Test.startTest(); 
database.executeBatch (pb,30); 
Test.stopTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

You control the `HttpMock` class that pretends it returns results from SAP callout in the test. Nothing stops you from going there and making it return 2 records (1 with amount below 50K, 1 with amount above), or multiple statuses or whatever else you need.